# Reordering multiple x-axis by negative values ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am now using R and ggplot to generate plot chart,
the table I have is by options and gender:
[before melt table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0glG0.png)

options are from -5~+5

in order to generate bar chart, melted it like this:
[melted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHIBo.png)

I used the code as follows to generate bar chart compares different gender frequency in each option:

```
ggplot(data=merge_df_melted, 
       aes(x = reorder(option,-value), y = value, group = variable, fill = variable))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(y = "number", x = "option", fill = "gender")
```

However, it orders by the number of each option, like the axis becomes `-5, -4, 5, -3, 3, 4, 0, -1, 2, -2, 1` instead of `-5, -4, -3, -2, -1`

I have tried ordering the melted table, but after it melted, it turns to 22 options because there are in the meantime both female and male data.

Do I need to add a column counting the count of each option in both gender or something? Because in the end I also want to add count labels on each bar

I will keep checking whether there are already duplicate questions

The chart I got:
[The chart I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPUU6.png)

The chart I want:
[The chart I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYuIf.png)

Comment: You are reordering the x axis by bar size, if you want the numeric order, have you tried *not reordering* at all? What am I missing?

Comment: is your option (i.e. -5 to 5) a number, a character, a factor? If the "option" column contains numeric and/or integer elements, the order should appear correctly (i.e. you shouldn't be having issues, so I assume it might be a char or a factor). Therefore, use str() function str(df_melted) to display the structure of your dataframe and convert your column, if needed. If you decide to convert it to a factor, you will want to specify the order.

Comment: @xan Just checked "option" was factor and converted it to numeric, but still not well ordered. 
@RuiBarradas Also tried not ordering, so I found I mistook the reordering part (that should be `x = reorder(option, option)` if I want to order it by option. 
And it did work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HazelLin well in your plot you are reordering your x-axis by y value, so it makes sense that your x axis is order by max to min y values. Therefore, if you remove the re-ordering bit it should work

Comment: Welcome to SO @HazelLin. Please include your data as code, and not an image. You can do this with `dput(merge_df_melted)`. This will make it easier for us to help you.